# what is the correct way of setting httpOnly cookie in the browser with CORS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, fetch, cross-domain

I have a node js server running on https://foo.test.com where the authentication API returns an httpOnly cookie which is not being set in the browser while site is on https://bar.test.com.

**Setting cookie from the server side:**

```js
ctx.cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 8.64e+7,
  sameSite: 'strict',
  secure: true,
  domain: 'test.com',
});
```

**CORS configuration**

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://bar.test.com',
    credentials: true,
})).use(bodyParser()).use(jwt).use(router.routes());
```

**Client side authentication api**

```js
fetch('/validate-otp', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }, 
  credentials: 'include',   
})
```

I have set up a test API on the server to see if the cookie is set as a header as shown below even though it's not working for the time being.

```js
fetch('/test', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

Inside the browser, I can see I have received the cookie with the response but it's not being set.
[image: Inspect -> Network][image: Inspect -> Application -> Cookies]

How can I properly set the httpOnly cookie in the browser so I can send it as a header with future server requests?

Comment: This is probably a client side issue. Did you set `withCredentials = true` on the `xhr` object? Please share the browser's code.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is automatically attached to all requests after it's been set. I'd start off by changing the `maxAge`. Since the measurement unit is milliseonds, your cookie will not live enough to be sent (60*60ms = 3600ms = 3.6s), maybe something like `maxAge: 8.64e+7` - that corresponds to 24 hours - could work.

The `httpOnly` attribute prevents any client-side javascript to access it, but that's a reasonable behavior for authentication purposes such yours.

Comment: I have tried and I don't think the maxAge is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper I have solved my issue by changing the fetch method from "PUT" to "POST" for the authentication API that gets the cookies from the server.